# Find the solution set of $\frac{3\sqrt{2-x}}{x-1}<2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Find the solution set of $\frac{3\sqrt{2-x}}{x-1}<2$

Start by squaring both sides
$$\frac{-4x^2-x+14}{(x-1)^2}<0$$
Factoring and multiplied both sides with -1
$$\frac{(4x-7)(x+2)}{(x-1)^2}>0$$
I got
$$(-\infty,-2)\cup \left(\frac{7}{4},\infty\right)$$
Since $x\leq2$ then
$$(-\infty,-2)\cup \left(\frac{7}{4},2\right]$$

But the answer should be $(-\infty,1)\cup \left(\frac{7}{4},2\right]$. Did I missed something?

Comment: you mean $x\le2$ ?

Comment: From $-3<2$ it doesn't follow that $(-3)^2<2^2$.

Comment: seems similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3265823/what-am-i-doing-wrong-solving-sqrtx21-2x10)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $\dfrac{3\sqrt{2-x}}{x-1}$ to be defined, $x\le2$ and $x\ne1$.

If $x<1,$ then the expression is negative (i.e., $<0$), so of course it is $< 2$.

If $x>1,$ then, as you showed, the inequality holds when $x>\dfrac74$.

Therefore, the solution set is $x<1$ or $\dfrac74<x\le2$.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest answers are the best +1

Answer (score 0):

Define $f(x)=\frac{3\sqrt{2-x}}{x-1}-2$.  Being continuous on its domain $(-\infty,2]\setminus\{1\}$,the function may change its sign only at its zero $7/4$  or at its singularity, namely at $1$. Now check the sign of $f$ in the corresponding intervals $(-\infty,1)$, $(1,7/4)$ and $(7/4,2]$; you want $f(x)<0$.

Comment: The downvote was what for?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but $-2$ is not a zero of $f(x)$

Comment: Holy macaron, how dumb of me.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The radicand cannot be negative, so we must have $x\le 2.$ Also, the denominator is negative for $x\lt 1.$ Thus, you must consider this in the two cases when

(1) $x\lt 1,$ or when

(2) $1\lt x\le 2.$

What you've done (which depends crucially on your first step of *squaring both sides*) works only with the assumption in case (2), since then we have that $\text {LHS}\ge 0.$ Thus you can square both sides. In the first case, you **cannot** since then $\text {LHS}\lt 0$ whereas $\text {RHS}\gt 0.$ This is not true in general since, for example, the fact that $-3<1$ does not imply that $9=(-3)^2<1.$

Thus, in the first case you need to approach with a different method. In particular multiply both sides by the negative quantity $x-1$ to get $$3\sqrt{2-x}>2(x-1),$$ which is obviously true for any $x<1,$ since then $\text {LHS}\gt 0$ and $\text {RHS}\le 0.$ Thus the solution in this case is $$(-\infty,1),$$ as wanted.